# print v/s return confusion in Error handling

Tags: python-3.x, function, error-handling, return

My First function is:

```
def conversion_one(x):
    try:
        if x >0:
            x = x*2
            print(x)
        else:
            print(-1*x)
    except TypeError: 
        conversion_one(int(x))
    except:
        print("there is an error")

    finally:
        print(type(x))
```

When I run this I get the following output

```
conversion_one('-3')
3
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```

If you see the code sequence then my intuition is:

1) Capture the error and run the complete code and print type of 'x'(inside finally)

2) Runs whatever inside "except TypeError" which implies conversion of string to int.

3) **Now according to the flow it is satisfying else condition so  why didn't it execute print(-1*x) instead of executing finally: print(type(x)) first ?**

My Second Function is:(In this I used return in conditional statement instead of using print)

```
def conversion_two(x):
    try:
        if x >0:
            x = x*2
            return(x) #In conversion_one() I used print
        else:
            return(-1*x) #In conversion_one() I used print
    except TypeError:
        conversion_two(int(x))
    except:
        print("there is an error")

    finally:
        print(type(x))
```

Output of my second function is:

```
conversion_two('-3')
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```

**Why output of conversion_two is not giving any conversion ?**

My third function is:

```
def conversion_three(x):
    try:
        if x >0:
            x = x*2
            return(x)
        else:
            return(-1*x)
    except TypeError:
        print(conversion_three(int(x))) #used print which is missing in 
                                    #conversion_one() and conversion)_two()
    except:
        print("there is an error")

    finally:
        print(type(x))
```

Output of my third function is:

```
conversion_three('-3')
<class 'int'>
3
<class 'str'>
```

My fourth function is:

```
def conversion_four(x):
    try:
        if x >0:
            x = x*2
            return(x)
        else:
            return(-1*x)
    except TypeError:
        print(conversion_four(int(x)))
    except:
        print("there is an error")

    finally:
        print(type(x))
```

Output from My fourth function is :-

```
conversion_four('-3')
<class 'int'>
3
<class 'str'>
```

**Can anyone please help me to understand why I am getting strange output in all four function and why the sequence of output is different in all four?**